# Получить значение переменной из другого класса

Tags: java

Делаю простенькие часики и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: внутри класса значение переменной есть, а если я вызываю эту переменную из другого класса, создав предварительной экземпляр этого класса, то значение ее null.
Где-то загвоздка... Помогите разобраться....

```
public class mainFrame extends JFrame {
    public Clock MoscowClock = new Clock();
    public Timer MoscowClockTimer = new Timer(500, MoscowClock);
    String settime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainFrame frame = new mainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public mainFrame() {
        /*другой код с настройками формы */
        MoscowClockTimer.start();
        settime = MoscowClock.gettime;
        System.out.println("MoscowClock.gettime " + MoscowClock.gettime);  //Проверки в консоль - дает null
        System.out.println("settime " + settime);  //Проверки в консоль - дает null

        public static class Clock implements ActionListener {
            public DateFormat df;
            public Date time;
            public String reportDate;
            public String gettime;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                reportDate = df.format(time);
                System.out.println("reportDate " + reportDate);
                get_time(reportDate);

            }

            public void get_time(String reportDate) {
                gettime = reportDate;
                System.out.println("gettime " + gettime); // Проверка в консоль - дает время, каждую секунду
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Названия классов надо писать с большой буквы

Comment: Исправил, но ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1):

```
settime = MoscowClock.gettime;
```

MoscowClock.gettime не инициализированная переменная. Ей надо сначала дать какое-то значение.

Comment: в самом классе Clock проинициализировал
public String gettime = null;

а перед settime = MoscowClock.gettime; 
проинициализировать MoscowClock.gettime ведь никак больше нельзя, это ж вызов переменной другого класса...а она инициализирована...в общем не получилось ничего

Comment: @TimLeyden Так вот именно и получается, что она проинициализирована как null, и в итоге и получается что печатается null.

Answer (score 1):

В процессе выполнения нигде не вызывается

```
public void get_time(String reportDate)
```

Таким образом поле `gettime` не инициализируется. Поэтому оно равно `null`.
Добавь в конструктор `Clock` метод `get_time(String reportDate)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static class Clock implements ActionListener{
        public DateFormat df;
        public Date time;
        public String reportDate;
        public String gettime;
        public static String t;

        public Clock() {
                t = reportDate;
                System.out.println("t :" + t);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
             time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
             reportDate = df.format(time);
             System.out.println("reportDate:" + reportDate);
```

Даже сократил чтобы проще было разобраться... по таймеру в основном классе происходит событие каждую секунду, листенер его ловит и каждую секунду делает запрос времени, результат добавляется в переменную reportDate, ее я вызываю в экземпляре класса в основном классе, но там она равна null, а если ее пытаться присвоить другой переменной в конструкторе Clock, то она тоже равна null, да и вообще значение конструктора вычисляется только при запуске, а не каждую секунду... что-то я совсем запутался